# How to create a folder structure in URL using java?

Tags: java

I want to create a folder structure to connected URL location. I am able read file from connected URL location, but note able to create a folder. Here is my code to read file from URL.

```
public class ReadFromURL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String urlToConnect = "http://11.111.111.2/UploadedFiles/test/";

        String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Just generate some unique random value.

        URLConnection connection = null;
        URL url  = null;

        try {
            url= new URL("http://11.111.111.2/UploadedFiles/test");
            connection = url.openConnection();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        connection.setDoOutput(true); // This sets request method to POST.
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

        int responseCode = 0;
        try {
            responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
            URL url1 = new URL("http://11.111.111.2/UploadedFiles/test/test.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url1.openStream()));

            String FILENAME = "D:\\test\\filename.txt";
            // write the output to stdout
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {

                write_to_file(FILENAME,line);
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            // close our reader
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(responseCode);         
    }

    public static void write_to_file(String filename,String line)
    {
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;

        try {

            //String content = "This is the content to write into file\n";

            fw = new FileWriter(filename);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(line);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                if (bw != null)
                    bw.close();

                if (fw != null)
                    fw.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give us the error message that you get?

Comment: Sorry,I didn't try any sample for creating a folder structure in that location.I need some sample. In URL( http://11.111.111.2/UploadedFiles/test/) directories are available till this path I want to create a Test2 directory  like http://11.111.111.2/UploadedFiles/test/Test2